# Are strong monomorphisms coretrations in the category of graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Consider the category of digraphs with strong homomorphisms as the morphisms. Here a strong homomorphism $f: G\longrightarrow H$, is a graph homomorphism which preserves and reflects adjacency of vertices in $G$ and $H$. It is true that strong monomorphisms(resp. epimorphisms) are injective (resp. surjective) in this category. Is it also true that every strong monomorphism(resp. epimorphisms) is a coretration (resp. retraction) in this category?

Comment: This may depend on the specifics of your category. Do you allow loops in your graphs? What about multiple edges?

Comment: @tcamps. Thank you for your comment. We may consider finite or infinite graphs with loops and multiple edges. May I ask how these conditions affect the question?

Comment: If you don't allow loops, then there is an obstruction to certain retractions in that the retraction can't identify any two points with an edge between them.  Also, "strong epimorphism  / monomorphism" has a [specific meaning](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strong+epimorphism) in category theory. But I take it that you just mean "epimorphism / monomorphism in the category of strong homomorphisms", right?

Answer (score 1):

Here's monomorphism which is not a coretraction (I like the alternate term "section" coming from geometry). Let $G$ a graph with one vertex called "$0$" and no edges. Let $H$ be the graph with the two vertices $\{0,1\}$ and an edge between them. Let $f: G \to H$ be the monomorphism sending $0 \mapsto 0$. Then there is no retraction of $f$ because there is nowhere for it to send the edge.

Here's an epimorphism which is not a retraction. Let $H$ be as above, and let $K$ be a graph with one vertex called "$0$" and one loop at that vertex. Let $g: H \to K$ be the unique homomorphism. Then $g$ has no section because there's nowhere to send the loop.

The first example, but not the second, would be fixed by working with *reflexive graphs*, i.e. graphs where every vertex has a distinguished loop and the homomorphisms are required to preserve the distinguished loop. But here's another example of a non-retract monomorphism that works for reflexive graphs too. Let $G$ be as above, and let $L$ be the graph with 3 vertices $\{0,1/2,1\}$, and an edge from $0$ to $1/2$ and from $1/2$ to $1$. Then the obvious inclusion from $G$ to $L$ has no retraction.